# How do I reference a variable inside a function in a class in python from another external file in python?

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I have following definitions in class. Don't worry about indentation please:

```
class A(objectRef //imported from another file):
    def doSomething(self, object):
        self.var1 = object.get("something");
```

Then I have another file with functions, but my reference is outside function in fileB.
FileB.py contains

```
1) ref = A().doSomething.var1
2) ref = A().doSomething(self.var1)
3) val = A().doSomething().val1
These did not work.
```

Unfortunately its not a function its variable reference which are used in for loops later.
The variable is then
Then, I need to extract var1 from another file where no function exist. Importing part is easy for class but then how do I reference to get var1 from another file.

`doSomething()` has hundreds of attributes referenced so unfortunately I won't be able to modify anything inside that. I would need to make things work from fileB.py as that is the one that needs to call `class A()`

Comment: From what I'm seeing your question does not have anything to do with different files or modules, but that you are just struggling with understanding how classes and methods work in Python. That's OK! But I suggest going back to whatever manual or book you're learning from and study more on classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want var1 then just do

```
obj = A()
obj.doSomething()
val = obj.var1
```

Comment: Hi, I had already tried this as first thing which had not worked.  `val = A().doSomething().val1`. This was my solution as well. Instead of using 3 lines you could use one line in my above example ? This did not work for me and it threw error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute`

Comment: Please read Anand's answer very carefully. What they wrote and what you ran are not the same thing.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I tried exactly what was in solution above and i got attribute error. But, before trying that I had previously tried another solution which I presented above in my solution.

Comment: If your class `A` is defined exactly the same as in your question, and you use it exactly the same as in this answer, you will not get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: ```TypeError: doSomething() missing 1 required positional argument obj```. I think my issue now might be in parameter in class A where A has an object parameter passed in. But, thank you everyone for effort.

Comment: Yeah in your problem the member function was not getting any self parameter, that's why you were facing the issue. So I also updated your question. You can crosscheck the edit version. Thanks

Comment: Hey Anand, the problem mainly now is A() class has parameter and doSomething() also has parameter. Unfortunately I can not pass parameter, if I do import whatever object has been passed as parameter in class A() then it triggers `TypeError`. I have updated my question even more.

Comment: You cannot pass an object as a base class of A. That is not inheritance and it is incorrect. To pass an object to a class you have to use __init__ function.

Comment: Oh my god, I am not asking to use inheritance at all. I am using single variable which is thrown somewhere in another python file. init is a constructor which will initialize data. I know that very well I think you did not get me somewhere in comment. My problem at the end had become maybe python configuration file did not get loaded at right time so did not get value updates.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to do it in the form `A().doSomething().var1`, you can add

```py
        return self
```

to your `A.doSometing` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant update A() class as it has thousands of lines. I have to make it work anyhow by modifying doSomething() in a way Iguananaut suggested but thanks.